# Magento 2 : order email does not have Add extra text field in checkout billing address

Tags: magento2

I have used this Plugin to add extra fields in checkout billing address.
https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form/
this is adding fields in billing address and in order. But these extra fields are not showing in Order Email received by customer.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to say that you have custom fields in your site checkout page, but now in your email template on Magento 2 for new order don't have any variable's to add?